# Based on Selected Data, get different picklist value in salsforce?

Tags: picklist

I have requirement like based on Work Order Service Type, Activity picklist value different like:

if Repair : then picklist value should be Repair and Other. If Other : then picklist value should be all.

[image]

Please suggest how I can achieve this, do I need to customization or with config we can do this. Tried multiple ways didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you try Dependent Picklists?

Comment: Yes, dependent list won't work here, because Work Order Service is a lookup and based on  this service type I have to set pick list value. Dependent Picklists, I am able to do on Labour Type and Activity, not with  Work Order Service and Activity.